# Why must I create a new user when beginning to use PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, odoo

After reading some tutorials on installing PostgreSQL, I know that I must create a new OS user such as 'PostgreSQL' in the process of installing. However, I don't know the reason and what would happen if I just use my current user account?
The same question on Odoo.

My Account Setting

[image]

Comment: In a nutshell: for security reasons. But the OS user is typically called `postgres` and is also typically automatically created when installing Postgres e.g. through `apt-get`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to define a "database owner". Normaly you use SQL on a Server with multible access accounts.

Nothing would happen if you use your own account to install it or define it as DB owned.

You should just recognize some PostgresSQL  services running with you local account under der "services" section....

Comment: Thank you! And I have deleted 'PostgreSQL' account! I can't stand this extra account :)

Comment: @Pulga: on Windows this will work, but if you do that on Linux, that will  break Postgres